# How to check type of variable inside ng-class?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

```
<div ng-class="{
    'undefined' : typeof object.property === 'undefined',
    'edit-active' : open == true
  }"> 
      {{ object.property }} 
</div>
```

This gives me a syntax error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'object.property' is unexpected, expecting [}]
```

How can I check if `object.property` is defined?

**Note: I am using angular 1.2.28.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need check is there smth, you can do much simplier

```
<div ng-class="{
    'undefined' : !object.property,
    'edit-active' :open == true
  }"> 
      {{ object.property }} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

typeof operator wouldnt work inside angular expression. However you can have a function in scope to do it.

```
<div ng-class="{
    'undefined' : checkType(object.property),
    'edit-active' : open == true
  }"> 
      {{ object.property }} 
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.checkType = function(prop) {
    return typeof prop === 'undefined';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too

Create a filter:

```
.filter('isUndefined', [function() {
  return function(input) {
    return typeof input === 'undefined';
  }
}]);
```

Use the filter in `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-class="{
    'empty' : object.property == '' || (object.property | isUndefined),
    'edit-active' : open == true
  }">
    {{object.property}}
</div>
```